# How to make autocomplete backspace work in this case

Tags: jquery

As User types in the input i am searching the table and displaying results accordingly .

I have put up a condition to check , if the length of the entered input is at least greater than or equal to 2 .(but after clearing the values its not showing up all values ??)

This is my code

```
$('#searchequip').keyup(function (){
    if ($(this).val().length >= 2) {
        $('#errmsgnoequip').hide();
        var val = $.trim(this.value).toUpperCase();
        var noElem = true;
        $('.mt-checkbox').each(function (){
            var parent = $(this).closest('li'),
            length = $(this).text().length > 0;
            if (length && $(this).text().search(new RegExp(val, 'i')) < 0)
            {
                parent.fadeOut('slow');
            } else {
                noElem = false;
                parent.show();
            }
        });
        if (noElem)
            $('#errmsgnoequip').html('No Results Matched').show();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e08o7uct/34/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is small change in your code, below code will work

```
$('#searchequip').keyup(function (){
if ($(this).val().length >= 2) {
    $('#errmsgnoequip').hide();
  var val = $.trim(this.value).toUpperCase();
  var noElem = true;
  $('.mt-checkbox').each(function (){
    var parent = $(this).closest('li'),
    length = $(this).text().length > 0;
    if (length && $(this).text().search(new RegExp(val, 'i')) < 0)
    {
      parent.fadeOut('slow');
    }else{
      noElem = false;
      parent.show();
    }
  });
  if (noElem)
    $('#errmsgnoequip').html('No Results Matched').show();
    } else {
        $("#equipdetails li").show();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing any action when the length of the value is less than 2. Therefore not showing back the hidden results.

You can add an `else` clause to your length checking condition. If the length of the value is less than 2 and the key pressed is backspace, display everything. (so if length is 1 but the user pressed a letter it does nothing)

```
$('#searchequip').keyup(function (e){    
   if ($(this).val().length >= 2) {
       // your filter
   } else if (e.keyCode == 8){   // 8 = backspace
       $('.mt-checkbox').closest('li').show(); // show everything hidden
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#searchequip').keyup(function (){
 if ($(this).val().length >= 2) {
    $('#errmsgnoequip').hide();
  var val = $.trim(this.value).toUpperCase();
  var noElem = true;
  $('.mt-checkbox').each(function (){
    var parent = $(this).closest('li'),
    length = $(this).text().length > 0;
    if (length && $(this).text().search(new RegExp(val, 'i')) < 0)
    {
      parent.fadeOut('slow');
    }else{
      noElem = false;
      parent.show();
    }
  });
  if (noElem)
    $('#errmsgnoequip').html('No Results Matched').show();      
    } else {
        $("#equipdetails li").show();
        $('#errmsgnoequip').html("");        
    }
});
```